# Name for Markov chain that eventually ends up in a recurrent class?

Tags: probability, reference-request, markov-chains

I am interested in Markov chains $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb{N}}$ (discrete time countable state space) such that regardless of initial distribution $X_0$, the chain eventually ends up in some recurrent class. Is there a name for this property that I could use to search for it?

Comment: When you talk about the chain ending up in "some recurrent class," are you referring to an absorption state (i.e. a state $x$ where $p(x, x) = 1$?) Or do you mean that there is some recurrent sub-chain that is eventually entered (but that the chain is free to move about between states within that sub-chain)?

Comment: I mean that with probability $1$, $X_t \in R$ for some $t$, where $R$ is the set of recurrent states.

Comment: Forgive me; I deleted my answer because it was at best unclear and at worst not an answer. But the closest thing to an answer I can muster is: you'd either just call the chain recurrent (if it's irreducible), or I think you'd just say that there is a closed collection of "final" or "essential" states (and that this is a recurrent collection). One might also call this an absorbing set. I'm not aware of language that would apply to the chain in this case, though it may exist.